# Простой новостной агрегатор на Android

Tags: android, c#, парсер

Всем привет! Есть желание сделать простой профильный агрегатор новостей под Android. Делать планирую на C# и Xamarin.Forms. Делать буду больше программу для себя изучая разработку в процессе. Планирую парсить только название статьи, краткое описание и ссылку на статью и выводить всё это в listview с 5-10 сайтов. По нажатию - переход к статье по ссылке через webview. И возникло несколько вопросов к архитектуре приложения:

1) На сколько сложно будет обычному смартфону (нагрузка ЦП + трафик) спарсить и обработать скажем 10 сайтов, если делать через AngleSharp (или ему подобных)? Или лучше сразу отказаться от парсинга на смартфоне и подумать об обработки на сервере скажем через php + sql?

2)Если я всё это смогу реализовать и захочу в дальнейшем выложить программу в Play Market её пропустят, если вся обработка источников будет на стороне смартфона (нарушаю ли я этим какие ограничения)?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Парсить вполне телефону по силам. У меня есть такое приложение и всё норм. А так-то да - лучше на серваке парсить и приложению с него через API брать данные - так надёжнее в смысле изменений `HTML`-кода сайтов - приложение не надо будет обновлять, только сервак.
2. Про ограничения такие не слышал. По крайней мере в смысле парсинга данных на стороне телефона. А вот за использование данных с сайтов без подтверждения права на это может стать проблемой. Если сами сайты где-то пишут, что их данные можно свободно использовать или их владельцы вам дадут согласие, то можно в гугловую техподдержку написать перед выкладыванием и эти разрешения показать - тогда они не заблокируют приложение при проверке.

Comment: Разрешение нужно получать даже если я хочу парсить только название и краткое описание (description) к статье? Контент ведь будет загружаться по переходу на сам сайт через браузер? Или я не так понимаю права на использование данных?

Comment: @AndreyBaryshnikov, тут уж только юрист разберётся. Я думаю, что норм будет, но я тут не специалист. Я писал про сам контент сайтов. Возможно и краткое описание к нему вполне относится.

Comment: Зависит еще от страны владельца сайта. 
Лучше задайте напрямую вопрос этим сайтам и получите письменный ответ можно/нельзя

Comment: С этим вопросом придётся разбираться отдельно. А заголовки в виде ссылок хоть можно собирать без разрешения? Если нет, то весь смысл программы отпадает...

Comment: @AndreyBaryshnikov, наверное можно. Но точно вам сказать смогут только на форуме для юристов)